# Error while generating chart for daily average PM2.5 concentrations in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, satellite, copernicus, air-quality

I was trying to generate a chart for daily average PM2.5 concentrations for January 2021. The satellite image I am using is [Copernicus Atmosphere Monitoring Service (CAMS) Global Near-Real-Time](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/ECMWF_CAMS_NRT#description).

Here is my code:

```
//Boundary Import
var boundary = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ee-u1805004/assets/ROI_DOE');

//To Visualize Boundary
Map.addLayer(boundary, {color: 'blue'}, 'DoE Boundary');
Map.centerObject(boundary, 17);

//Import Dataset
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/CAMS/NRT");

//Filter the dataset
var filtered_dataset = dataset.select('particulate_matter_d_less_than_10_um_surface')
                       .filter(ee.Filter.date('2022-01-01', '2022-01-20'))
                       .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(boundary));

//Checking the number of Image Collection
print(filtered_dataset.size());

//Chart Generation

var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection: filtered_dataset,
  regions: boundary,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 44528,
}).setChartType('LineChart')
.setOptions({
  title: 'Daily PM2.5 Concentration Time Series',
  hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
  vAxis: {title: 'PM2.5 Concentration'},
});

// Display the chart
print(chart);
```

I'm getting this error:

> "Error generating chart: Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type
> string"

for Copernicus Atmosphere Monitoring Service (CAMS).

Could you help me figure out where I made a mistake?

Comment: The script didn't give me any error. You didn't share your boundary asset, so I used a random one.